# How to latest version of Node JS on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7

My workflow requires nodejs v16 but because of the platform checks the new version isn't available on Windows 7. The reason I have been using Windows 7 still is because I have a really poorly performing Computer with only 4GB ram. Trying some things on the internet have enabled me to install v15 but still some tasks require the new version. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you create an environment variable called: NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK and set it to 1, node 16.6.2 will run on Windows 7.  I have not tried any later versions than that, and 16.13 has been reported by others as not working.  (Later versions of node use a version of libuv that doesn't support Windows 7, and so will not run even with the environment variable set.)